# Llamar una consulta nativa JPA con parametros

Tags: jpa, ejb

Para solicitar su ayuda, tengo la siguiente consulta que me devuelve una lista agrupada de forma normal esa consulta la tengo desde mi facade y la inicializo desde mi controlador me trae una lista asociada a un objeto,pero quiero una consulta que me devuelva una lista pero con un parametro, pero no se cuando quiero hacerla desde mi facade no se como enviarle el parametro a la consulta desde el controlador.

ejemplo de consulta normal

```
public List<PickingPedidos> obtenerLista() {
    Query q = em.createNativeQuery("select g.cliente, g.documentno, g.name from PICKING_PEDIDOS G\n"
            + "GROUP BY g.cliente, g.documentno, g.name", PickingPedidos.class);
    List<PickingPedidos> listado = q.getResultList();
    return listado;
}
```

Esto lo inicializo en mi bean de la siguiente forma

```
private List<PickingPedidos> pickingPedidosList;
@PostConstruct
public void inicializarBean() {
pickingPedidosList = vistaPedidoFacade.obtenerLista();
}
```

Ahora lo que necesito hacer es lo mismo pero con una consulta con parametros desde mi controlador.

```
public List<PickingPedidos> obtenerLista1() {
    Query q = em.createNativeQuery("select g.cliente, g.documentno, g.name from PICKING_PEDIDOS G\n"
            + "FROM  g.documentno = ?", PickingPedidos.class);
    List<PickingPedidos> listado = q.getResultList();
    return listado;
}
```

Pero necesito llamar esta lista con un parametro dinamico desde mi controlador,¿Como lo hago dinamico?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer usando un `createQuery` lo único que si vas a traer todos los datos del objeto `PickingPedidos`, lo que no se si documento es un `String` pero suponiendolo te dejo un ejemplo para hacerlo

```
public List<PickingPedidos> obtenerLista1(String documento) {

List<PickingPedidos> listado = em.createQuery("SELECT G FROM PickingPedidos G WHERE 
G.documento =:documento ", PickingPedidos.class)
.setParameter("documento", documento)
.getResultList();

return listado;
}
```

> **Nota**: revisando tu consulta falta el `where` y no se si esta bien escrito el campo **documentno** tiene que ser el mismo nombre que en la base de datos.

Comment: Ok voy a mirar si tengo un error.